# os.startfile error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, file, spyder

I am running this in Spyder on windows 7. 
I have tested this on multiple files, all of different types.

```
file = r'c/:folder/file.txt'
os.startfile(file)
```

returns

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:/folder/file.txt'
```

I have also tried to check if the filenames are correct, and os.path.isfile(file) returns True

Comment: What if you do `file = r'c:\folder\file.txt'`? I mean, I don't understand why there is no slash after`c:`

Comment: Ah, I forgot to type it. The real file path I am using was copied from file explorer. I messed up typing the fake address. will edit

Comment: If it's a win environment why are you using unix style path specified. Try, C:\folder\file.txt

Comment: And if you try to do `os.startfile(os.path.normpath(file))`?

Comment: C:\folder\file works great! I just used what was copied from copy and pasting the file in, and did not question it. I understand now, Thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

As stated by @olinox14 :

```
os.startfile(os.path.normpath(file))
```

It is most likely that there is a problem in reading the path file. Os can fix that for you. I've had the same problem